# Is Jedi VCS compatible with Windows 8.1?

Tags: delphi, jedi

Has anyone managed to correctly run Jedi VCS Stand Alone Client on Windows 8.1?
I tried but get an exception when syncing files.

"JEDI VCS is unable to create a local copy of this file.
 Exception. Unable to create target directory:  in [CreateTargetDir]"

I would like to transition to Windows 8 for my Delphi work but if I can not use Jedi then I will have to stay on Windows 7.

**Installed Software:**

- OS : Windows 8.1
- Jedi VCS Client: 2.45.820

**Some more detail:**

- I can log in and view projects no issues
- I can not sync project due to above error
- I have full permissions to target directory (Even deleted and recreated permissions for user on folder)
- I can manually create and add files and folders to the sync directory. Only Jedi VCS has the issue.
- Target directory is a sub folder of C:. eg C:\MyDev\
- I am a member of the admin group on the PC
- Thinking the issue was the install location of C:\Program Files (x86), I installed to C:\Programs instead. Same error.
- I tried running Jedi VCS as administrator. From right click Run as Administrator and from   setting same option on shortcut.

**Final Test:**

I just tested the Jedi VCS client integrated into Delphi 6 and 2006 IDEs. It is a bit 
cluncky but in fact works.

It is not really useable though. If you sync something large with many Delphi project 
files (such as  custom library or the like) you get a continuous stream of 
'syncronisation complete' messages pop up for every project file.

It is is ok for projects with a few project files though.

=============

Any help appreciated.

Peter Mayes

Comment: You could do some debugging. However, it would be utter folly in my view to choose this vcs over a modern dvcs likee git, mercurial, etc. Or even svn if you prefer that workflow model. There is huge tooling and community based around these mainstream vcs systems. JEDI vcs, not so much.

Comment: Are you sure your target dir is not virtualized?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction Free Consulting.

Comment: My sync directory is actually a subst on C:\MyDev\.  Running the subst command as administrator then allows JediVCS access to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. JediVCS is compatiable with Windows 8.1.

In the end you have to:

- Run JediVCS as administrator
- If you are syncing to a subst drive (which I actually was) then the subst command must have 
  been run as administrator. (Tested by right clicking my subst batch file -> Run as 
  Administrator option)

  If the subst is not run as administrator then JediVCS can not sync files to that location 
  successfully.